# How to read and process the formatted date like 01/11/1998, Sunday(10000 inputs) C++

Tags: c++, formatted-text

I need to read the date with weekday. First of all, i need to read the date and weekday then calculate the total weekday, for example:

```
total Sunday :1000
total Monday :1000
......
```

I always get the value is 0.
The input file looks like this:

```
23/10/2005, Sunday
26/07/2016, Tuesday
10/01/1995, Tuesday
14/10/2015, Wednesday
30/09/1982, Thursday
22/09/1993, Wednesday
21/05/1972, Sunday
23/01/2017, Monday
20/05/1974, Monday
27/11/1985, Wednesday
11/07/2005, Monday
06/09/2014, Saturday
16/03/1991, Saturday
09/03/1970, Monday
17/08/2015, Monday
04/05/2010, Tuesday
14/11/2013, Thursday
13/11/2015, Friday
08/10/1995, Sunday
07/09/1986, Sunday
.....
```

which there is 10000.

```
string line;

string day[7] = { "Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
ifstream infile("input.txt");
ofstream validfile("valid.txt");
ofstream invalidfile("invalid.txt");
int total = 0;
int date[2], month[2], year[4];
int Sunday = 0, Monday = 0, Tuesday = 0, Wednesday = 0, Thursday = 0, Friday = 0, Saturday = 0;
char symbol = '/';
char symbol2 = ',';

while (getline(infile, line)) {
    total = total++;
}
validfile << "Valid file\n" << "The total record :" << total << endl;


    while (!infile.eof()) {

        infile >> day[2] >> symbol >> month[2] >> symbol >> year[4] >> symbol2 >> line;

        if (line.compare(day[0]) == 0) {
            Sunday++;
        }
        else if (line.compare(day[1]) == 0) {
            Monday++;
        }
        else if (line.compare(day[2]) == 0) {
            Tuesday++;
        }
        else if (line.compare(day[3]) == 0) {
            Wednesday++;
        }
        else if (line.compare(day[4]) == 0) {
            Thursday++;
        }
        else if (line.compare(day[5]) == 0) {
            Friday++;
        }
        else if (line.compare(day[6]) == 0) {
            Saturday++;
        }
}

        cout << "Total Sunday :" << Sunday << endl;
        cout << "Total Monday :" << Monday << endl;
        cout << "Total Tuesday :" << Tuesday << endl;
        cout << "Total Wednesday :" << Wednesday << endl;
        cout << "Total Thursday :" << Thursday << endl;
        cout << "Total Friday :" << Friday << endl;
        cout << "Total Saturday :" << Saturday << endl;
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please run a debugger over your code to see where something is not doing what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: read a line, then use string find/substr on the line to find the comma, the weekday comes after that. convert it to lower case and use a `std::map<std::string, int>` to count occurrences and count lines as you read them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the 1st loop you've reach to end of file.

After you've reach the end of file you need to go back to the beginning before starting the 2nd loop:

```
//this is the 1st loop in your code:
while (getline(infile, line)) {
    total = total++;
}

validfile << "Valid file\n" << "The total record :" << total << endl;

//now you need to rewind:
infile.clear(); //clear EOF state
infile.seekg(0); //back to beginning

//then continue the 2nd loop
while (!infile.eof()) {
```

In addition: you have error in the following line:

```
infile >> day[2] >> symbol >> month[2] >> symbol >> year[4] >> symbol2 >> line;
```

For example: 
`infile >> day[2]`  will read only one character, not 2. also I guess you write to `day` instead of to `date`.
a possible solution is to use infile.get(date,2) to read 2 bytes, or to read line and copy substrings.

Comment: Not sure why, the process of debugging just keep running when i use infile.seekg(0)

Answer (score 2):

Variables `day`, `month` and `year` will **not** have the expected values from the following line of code, because the indexing means that you are writing to specific character positions within those arrays:

```
infile >> day[2] >> symbol >> month[2] >> symbol >> year[4] >> symbol2 >> line;
```

Here's an alternative, using `getline()` with the expected separator instead:

```
string line;
string day, month, year, weekday, space;
char separator = '/';
ifstream infile("input.txt");

while (getline(infile, line))
{
    ++total;
}

cout  << "total" << total << endl;
//do your stuff.

infile.clear(); 
infile.seekg(0); 
total=0; // just reinitialising to check, you can ignore.

while (getline(infile, day, separator) &&
       getline(infile, month,  separator) &&
       getline(infile, year,  ',') &&
       getline(infile, space,  ' ') &&
       getline(infile, weekday))
{
   ++total;
   cout << day << "-" << month<< "-"  << year << "-" << weekday<< endl;
   //Do your stuff. 
}
```

Documentation for `std::getline (string)` is available [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: `getline` does not take char as input argument. Please go throug getline documentation. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Answer (score 0):

**First problem**

Your declaration of the array holding weekday names isn't const:

```
string day[7] = ...
```

this will bite your later on (see #4).

**Second problem**

These:

```
int date[2], month[2], year[4];
```

are arrays. You don't want arrays, you simply want integers holding the value of day, month and year:

```
int date, month, year;
```

**Third problem**

Here:

```
while (getline(infile, line)) {
    ...
}
...
while (!infile.eof()) {
    ...
}
```

the second loop will **never** execute, because you get to the end of your file in the first loop.

**Fourth problem**

Everything you do here:

```
infile >> day[2] >> symbol >> month[2] >> symbol >> year[4] >> symbol2 >> line;
```

is as wrong and erroneous as it can be:

- Since your variable for storing the day integer is named `date`, you are actually writing to the third position in the array storing the names of weekdays. If `day` was const (see #1), you would get a compiler error, immediately pointing you to this mistake.
- You write outside the size of the arrays. E.g. `month` has size `2`, so you cannot write to index `2`, as it only has indices `0` and `1`. You shouldn't be using arrays anyways for this, see #2.
- You overwrite `symbol` and `symbol2`, instead of checking if the file contains them at the expected position.
- `line` will start with a space, as you only read the comma, but your file separates by comma and space.

**Fifth problem**

Your naming doesn't follow conventions:

```
int Sunday = 0, Monday = 0, Tuesday = 0, Wednesday = 0, Thursday = 0, Friday = 0, Saturday = 0;
```

While still legal code, you should stick to naming conventions, variable names start lower case. Also you should seriously think of better names for your variables. Make them **speak**, e.g. `weekDayNames` instead of `day`.

**Sixth problem**

You are not debugging your code, thus wasting everyone's time. Debug your code and you will **see** what's happening to your variables. You will **see** how often your loops are executed and what happens inside. Then you can figure out **where exactly** your code is going wrong and maybe even why.